# SSRS function needs to read field from additional dataset

Tags: function, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, custom-code

So in the custom code in SSRS this function is reading a field from a different data set. To be specific the field is "TOTAL_WORK_HOURS".

```
Public Function CRFtotalhourswobreak(Fields As Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Fields) As Double
Return Fields!TOTAL_WORK_HOURS.Value - CRFbreakhours(Fields)
```

End Function

Because that field is in a dataset not being used by the Tablix, the field simply isn't being read. I know this to be true because whenever I replace the field with random number, I do get results.

Is there proper syntax to implement a field that isn't in the main dataset?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
=First(Fields!TOTAL_WORK_HOURS.Value, "DataSet1")
```